# How can i make wget download only pages not css images etc?

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download an entire website using wget but I don't want wget to download images, videos etc.

I tried

```
wget -bqre robots=off -A.html example.com –user-agent=”Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6″
```

but when I do that it doesn't download .php files, just downloads static .html files.

Is there a solution to this problem with wget?

Answer (score 6):

You've explicitly told wget to only accept files which have `.html` as a suffix.

Assuming that the php pages have `.php`, you can do this:

```
wget -bqre robots=off -A.html,.php example.com –user-agent=”Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6″
```

Note that this will downloaded the rendered html, not the source of the php. If the page is sufficiently dynamic, you might not get the rendered result you expect.

However, I'd suggest that another tool such as [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) may do a better job - it depends on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I have to disagree with httrack doing a better job. I find its GUI buggy, unclear and in need of a good cleanup. Plus, wget has (almost) all the same options and is much more straigthforward. I have had only bad experiences with HTTRACK and I have played around with it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

-A takes  a list, so -A.html,.php should fit the bill.
You should also look in to -R (it also takes a reject list).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, and it's pretty simple. Take a look at this SO answer: https://superuser.com/questions/709702/how-to-crawl-using-wget-to-download-only-html-files-ignore-images-css-js

tl/dr; use `--follow-tags=a` which will follow only `a` tags.